# Google Maps v2 on Android: marker is too small

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to set a custom marker on google maps v2. I used

```
.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_custom))
```

to set it and it appears really small (about 1/3 of the custom marker). marker_custom is a png file 32x37 32-bit color.

```
protected Bitmap adjustImage(Bitmap image) {
int dpi = image.getDensity();
if (dpi == mDpi)
    return image;
else {
    int width = (image.getWidth() * mDpi + dpi / 2) / dpi;
    int height = (image.getHeight() * mDpi + dpi / 2) / dpi;
    Bitmap adjustedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    adjustedImage.setDensity(mDpi);
    return adjustedImage;
    }
}
```

I have already tried to resize the bitmap accordingly to the density of the screen by using:

and I also tried to use

```
.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerFreeBitmap))
```

but nothing changed.

Any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: how about using a drawable .png on the res folders.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a Drawable .png and placing the different sizes in the different drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-mdpi folders.

then create the marker using

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker_drawable)));
```

Comment: I have another png of the same size in another activity that is shown of the real size (bigger than the marker) on the same deivice, so I guess that is not the problem